# Register & read Telegram "Web push" notifications

Tags: c#, .net, web-push, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

Based on this [Telegram API link](https://core.telegram.org/api/push-updates):

> 10 - Web push (web push, see below)
> For 10 web push, the token must be a JSON-encoded object with the
> following keys:
>
> `endpoint`: Absolute URL exposed by the push service where the application server can send push messages
>
> `keys`: P-256 elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman parameters in the following object
>
> - `p256dh`: Base64url-encoded P-256 elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman public key
> - `auth`: Base64url-encoded authentication secret

1. How can I generate requested parameters to register the device?
2. Upon receiving at the endpoint URL, how should I decode incoming notification?

---

- Everything happens on a ASP.NET Web API server and without a browser frontend.
- I'm using WTelegramClient as wrapper around Telegram API